# mapbox how can I add a label to a linestring in python?

Tags: python, plotly, mapbox

This is a function that takes in coordinates and draw a circle and a line on a map. But I would like to add label to the line indicated the radius of the circle, like 1000m in this case.

Like this http://jsfiddle.net/brianssheldon/wm18a33d/27/
But this is javascript. Can I do this in python?

```py
def func(lat, lon):

    df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'lat': [lat],
        'lon': [lon]})
    gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
        df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.lon, df.lat))

    fig = px.scatter_mapbox(
        gdf, lat="lat", lon="lon"
    ).update_layout(mapbox={"style": "open-street-map"})

    gdf_ = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
        gdf, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(gdf.lon, gdf.lat))
    gdf_.set_crs(epsg=4386, inplace=True)

    utm = gdf_.estimate_utm_crs()
    gdf_ = gdf_.to_crs(utm)
    b = 1000
    m = b // 10
    p = gdf_.centroid.values[0]
    arrow = LineString(
        [p, (p.x + b, p.y), (p.x + b - m, p.y - m), (p.x + b - m, p.y + m), (p.x + b, p.y)]
    )


    def geojson(shape, utm):
        return gpd.GeoSeries([shape], crs=utm).to_crs("epsg:4386").__geo_interface__

    # add circle geometry as layer to mapbox figure
    fig.update_layout(
        mapbox={
            "layers": [
                {
                    "source": geojson(p.buffer(b), utm),
                    "color": "PaleTurquoise",
                    "type": "fill",
                    "opacity": 0.5,
                },
                {
                    "source": geojson(p.buffer(m), utm),
                    "color": "red",
                    "type": "fill",
                    "opacity": 0.5,
                },
                {
                    "source": geojson(arrow, utm),
                    "color": "blue",
                    "type": "line",
                    "opacity": 0.5,
                    "title": 'aaa',
                },
            ]
        }
    )
    return fig
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- this is all documented here: [layout mapbox](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/mapbox/)
- it suffers same issues as `text` parameter to
  `px.scattermapbox()`. Have to use a mapbox token and a mapbox *style*

```
import plotly.express as px
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import LineString

accessToken = "pk.eyJ1Ijoib2tpZWJ1YmJhIiwiYSI6ImNpdHZscGs3ajAwNXYyb284bW4ydWUzbGsifQ.1PoNrSP0F65WolWgqKhV4g"
style = "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9"
df = px.data.election()

# prep geometry
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(px.data.election_geojson())
gdf = gdf.join(
    gdf["geometry"].centroid.apply(lambda g: pd.Series({"lon": g.x, "lat": g.y}))
)

# plot circles at various lat / lon
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(
    df.merge(gdf, on="district"), lat="lat", lon="lon", size="total"
)
fig.update_layout(mapbox={"style": style, "accesstoken": accessToken})
# fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="carto-positron")

gdf_ = gdf.set_crs("epsg:4326").sample(1)
utm = gdf_.estimate_utm_crs()
gdf_ = gdf_.to_crs(utm)
b = 10000
m = b // 10
p = gdf_.centroid.values[0]
arrow = LineString(
    [p, (p.x + b, p.y), (p.x + b - m, p.y - m), (p.x + b - m, p.y + m), (p.x + b, p.y)]
)


def geojson(shape, utm, label=None):
    gdf_ = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[shape], crs=utm).to_crs("epsg:4386")
    if label:
        gdf_ = gdf_.assign(label=label)
    return gdf_.__geo_interface__


# add circle geometry as layer to mapbox figure
fig.update_layout(
    mapbox={
        "layers": [
            {
                "source": geojson(p.buffer(b), utm),
                "color": "PaleTurquoise",
                "type": "fill",
                "opacity": 0.5,
            },
            {
                "source": geojson(p.buffer(m), utm),
                "color": "red",
                "type": "fill",
                "opacity": 0.5,
            },
            {
                "source": geojson(arrow, utm),
                "color": "blue",
                "type": "line",
                "opacity": 0.5,
            },
            {
                "source": geojson(LineString([p, (p.x + b, p.y)]), utm, label="1000m"),
                "type": "symbol",
                "symbol": {
                    "text": "{label}",
                    "textfont": {"size": 12},
                    "placement": "line-center",
                },
            },
        ]
    }
)
```

[image]